# RelativeSource BindingExpression error

Tags: wpf, mvvm, relativesource

I am using a WPF `RelativeSource` `Binding` in a `DataTemplate` for one of my ViewModel classes, like so:

```
<DataTemplate x:Type="{x:Type ViewModelB}">
     <Grid Visibility="{Binding DataContext.MyBoolProperty, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, 
                        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
     </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

A root ViewModel, `ViewModelA`, has an instance of this ViewModel as a public property, and also has a `DataTemplate` for it, like this:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Type="{x:Type ViewModelA}">
      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ViewModelBProperty}" />
  </DataTemplate>
```

As you see, i want some stuff on the View for `ViewModelB` being triggered `Visible` or `Hidden` based on a property that is on `ViewModelA`.

This approach works fine.

However, `ViewModelA` itself is also presented in `ContentPresenter`. When i change the Content of this `ContentPresenter` (e.g. to `ViewModelC`), i am presented with some binding exceptions in my debug log, such as:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyBoolProperty' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModelC' (HashCode=56562781)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.MyBoolProperty; DataItem='ViewModelC' (Name=''); target element is 'Grid' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
```

I am guessing here, that the `Binding` to the DataContext gets updated before the actual view is disposed. What can be done to fix this behavior?

Comment: Should you not have FindAncestor in you binding ? like this .. <Grid Visibility="{Binding DataContext.MyBoolProperty, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}, 
                        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">

Comment: You are right, that is missing. However, it seems to be the default value, since it works without, and adding it makes no difference.

Comment: oh, ok I spot that in first look and thought it might be useful to have in place !

Comment: You don't have to fix every error that shows up in the console.  A correct application can end up showing many MANY binding errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this code by rewritting the binding logic alltogether. The binding is now no longer dependend on a property from ViewModelA. Still would be interested in knowing how one can solve such a issue.

Comment: Thought about it, but it is just another binding, but to a property on ViewModelB. Also it doesn't really solve the issue, but circumvent it.